# Bank for text files of different kinds?

Tags: file, text

This isn't really a programming question, but I want to do a little programming project, and for it I need a big text file that looks like this:

```
one
two
three
four
...
thirteen
fourteen
...
one hundred
...
```

The longer the list the better.

Is there some website that has loads of different text files such as this one available for free?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need specifically a website to create a text file for you, you can create one youself. Try using notepad if you're on windows.

Comment: Of course, but it takes time to make a giant text file with sequential numbers. That's why I wanted to know

Comment: what number were you looking to go up to

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need a text file that lists sequential numbers, or just a big text file with lots of lines of data?

If you just want a big file of randomish data you could use a lorum ipsum generator such as http://www.lipsum.com/

Just enter how much data you want in the file and download.

Comment: They should be sequential

Comment: If you have excel this might be useful : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel, you should be able to produce a big file quickly with this.